# use symget versus dereference with &

Tags: sas

Is it possible to use symget() instead of dereferencing the macro variable (&var1) somehow? in order to set the table: dataset1?

```
%let var1 = dataset1;

data one;
set symget('var1');
run;
```

Comment: Is there some other more fundamental problem that you're trying to solve here? Your question has [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) written all over it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - using [call set](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000127856.htm).

```
%let var1 = sashelp.class;

data one;
  length name $8 sex $1 age height weight 8. ;
  drop dsid;
  dsid=open(symget('var1'),"i");
  call set (dsid);
  i=1;
  do while (fetchobs(dsid,i)=0);
    output;
    i+1;
  end;
run;
```

The example above requires that the columns are pre-initialised, however it should also be possible to figure those out dynamically as well using the Vxxx functions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `symget` once a data step has started executing, so you can't use it to generate part of a set statement, except possibly with the use of something like `call execute`, and only then if you're generating code for a whole data step.

I won't elaborate further because I strongly suspect that there is probably a better way of doing whatever it is that you're really trying to do here.